# print to file javascript

Tags: javascript, io

I'm wondering.. how could I output a string to a file (and create said file) in javascript?

I'm using this for Chrome extension development.

Comment: A little more context please. Where's this file supposed to be written? Are you talking about Javascript running in a browser?

Answer (score 1):

You can't create, read, or modify files on the computer using browser based client side Javascript for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this from within a browser, it won't work except you might use activex or java (via plugins).

Or you fetch yourself the spidermonkey (mozilla's javascript engine) source code and compile it into a command line application. You will get file access this way.

Cheers,
-S

Answer (score 0):

You post the info to a http handler (ashx in asp.net, or just a php site), which then writes the info to a file.